# Residuals assumptions in glmm not verified! Help

Tags: residuals, glmm, glmmtmb, link-function, glmmadaptive

I am trying out GLMMs models to test whether two categorical variables (species and sex) and their interaction (sex + species + sex*species= fixed factors) influence certain acoustic parameters (response variable) of some vocalisations. My response variables are continuous numerical positive, such as the Fundamental frequency or duration of vocalizations. So, I'm trying different glmms for every acoustic parameter I have. My model has the ID as random factor, and the context of emission of vocalizations as another fixed variable. For each individual I have more than one observation, meaning that each individual vocalized more than once.

My response variables don't have a normal distribution, some of them are very asymmetrical, and one of them has two central humps. I have tried for example with the fundamental frequency, I've done a logarithmic transformation and used `gamma`, `gaussian` or `inverse.gaussian` with various link functions (`log`, `inverse`, `identity`), but when I check the assumptions (normality and homogeneity of residuals) these are not verified.

The general model setting is:

```r
full_F <- glmer(Fundam_freq ~ Sex + Breed + Sex*Breed + 
             Context + (1 | Cat_ID), data = data, family = ?(link = "?"))
```

**EXAMPLE WITH** `family=Gamma(link = "log")` after having *log-transformed + 1* the response variable. Here I attach images of checking residuals assumptions :(

1. Checking assumptions:

```r
DHARMa::simulateResiduals(fittedModel = full_F, plot = TRUE)
```

[image: photo 1]

2. Checking assumptions with:

```r
sjPlot::plot_model(full_F, type = "diag")
```

[image: photo 2]

3. Checking assumptions with:

```r
diagnostics.plot(full_F)
```

[image]

Which families and link functions do you recommend? Is there something I should do before run the glmm? (obviously, I transformed the Sex, Breed and Context into factors before run the model)

Comment: I would try a quantile model.  R has an lqmm package. Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13932/is-there-an-r-implementation-to-some-mixed-models-quantile-regression-statistica   .   This might be particularly helpful for the bimodal dependent variable.

Comment: Thank you @PeterFlom, I try with this option. Have you by chance an example of script with lqmm function?

Comment: I do not, but the R help page will have examples.

Comment: This doesn't look too terrible to me: the normality of residuals is the *least* important of the assumptions. Having to log-transform and then log again (via the Gamma link function) seems like a pretty strong transformation, and the Q-Q plot (deviating below on the lower end -> left-skewed, as confirmed by the residual histogram) suggests that you *over*-corrected (e.g. if you want to transform, something like sqrt + log or (?) an *inverse* transform of the original data, plus a linear mixed model (`lmer`), might work well.  Note that your *residuals*/conditional distrib is **not** bimodal ..

Comment: @BenBolker I really appreciate your suggestions, thank you! So, you're saying that I could try both sqrt and log together right, and then a lmer? Or inverse + lmer? With the transformation then the interpretation of the fixed factors on dependent variables become more complex...